# In akka-stream how to create a unordered Source from a futures collection

Tags: scala, future, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I need to create an `akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T, Unit]` from a collection of `Future[T]`.

E.g., having a collection of futures returning integers,

```
val f1: Future[Int] = ???
val f2: Future[Int] = ???
val fN: Future[Int] = ???
val futures = List(f1, f2, fN)
```

how to create a

```
val source: Source[Int, Unit] = ???
```

from it.

I cannot use `Future.sequence` combinator, since then I would wait for each future to complete before getting anything from the source. I want to get results in *any* order as soon as any future completes.

I understand that `Source` is a purely functional API and it should not run anything before somehow materializing it. So, my idea is to use an `Iterator` (which is lazy) to create a source:

```
Source { () =>
  new Iterator[Future[Int]] {
    override def hasNext: Boolean = ???
    override def next(): Future[Int] = ???
  }
}
```

But that would be a source of futures, not of actual values. I could also block on `next` using `Await.result(future)` but I'm not sure which tread pool's thread will be blocked. Also this will call futures sequentially, while I need parallel execution.

**UPDATE 2**: it turned out there was a much easier way to do it (thanks to Viktor Klang):

```
Source(futures).mapAsync(1)(identity)
```

**UPDATE**: here is what I've got based on @sschaef answer:

```
def futuresToSource[T](futures: Iterable[Future[T]])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Source[T, Unit] = {
  def run(actor: ActorRef): Unit = {
    futures.foreach { future =>
      future.onComplete {
        case Success(value) =>
          actor ! value
        case Failure(NonFatal(t)) =>
          actor ! Status.Failure(t) // to signal error
      }
    }

    Future.sequence(futures).onSuccess { case _ =>
      actor ! Status.Success(()) // to signal stream's end
    }
  }

  Source.actorRef[T](futures.size, OverflowStrategy.fail).mapMaterializedValue(run)
}

// ScalaTest tests follow

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

"futuresToSource" should "convert futures collection to akka-stream source" in {
  val f1 = Future(1)
  val f2 = Future(2)
  val f3 = Future(3)

  whenReady {
    futuresToSource(List(f1, f2, f3)).runFold(Seq.empty[Int])(_ :+ _)
  } { results =>
    results should contain theSameElementsAs Seq(1, 2, 3)
  }
}

it should "fail on future failure" in {
  val f1 = Future(1)
  val f2 = Future(2)
  val f3 = Future.failed(new RuntimeException("future failed"))

  whenReady {
    futuresToSource(List(f1, f2, f3)).runWith(Sink.ignore).failed
  } { t =>
    t shouldBe a [RuntimeException]
    t should have message "future failed"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a source of Futures and then "flatten" it via mapAsync:

```
scala> Source(List(f1,f2,fN)).mapAsync(1)(identity)
res0: akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[Int,Unit] = akka.stream.scaladsl.Source@3e10d804
```

Comment: What if my futures are ot type `Future[Source[T, Unit]]` - can I do something better than `Source(futures).mapAsyncUnordered(1)(identity).flatten(FlattenStrategy.concat)`? I'd like that flatten to be unordered and also support parallelism level.

Comment: I'm currently (whenever I find an hours or two) working on `flatten(FlattenStrategy.merge)` which would do what you want. In the mean time you can use `mapAsyncUnordered(par)(identity)` + a FlexiMerge implementation?

Comment: Viktor, I didn't look at FlexiMerge, will give it a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

One of the easiest ways to feed a Source is through an Actor:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import akka.actor._
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

implicit val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")

def run(actor: ActorRef): Unit = {
  import system.dispatcher
  Future { Thread.sleep(100); actor ! 1 }
  Future { Thread.sleep(200); actor ! 2 }
  Future { Thread.sleep(300); actor ! 3 }
}

val source = Source
  .actorRef[Int](0, OverflowStrategy.fail)
  .mapMaterializedValue(ref ⇒ run(ref))
implicit val m = ActorMaterializer()

source runForeach { int ⇒
  println(s"received: $int")
}
```

The Actor is created through the `Source.actorRef` method and made available through the `mapMaterializedValue` method. `run` simply takes the Actor and sends all the completed values to it, which can then be accessed through `source`. In the example above, the values are sent directly in the Future, but this can of course be done everywhere (for example in the `onComplete` call on the Future).

Comment: BTW, why the first `actorRef` argument is `0`? Does it matter?

Comment: If the consumer can take all the elements out of the Source you surely don't need a cache, therefore it is 0.

Comment: I tried, but zero didn't work (was throwing exception). Size equal to futures collection size worked fine.